# Returning placed and unplaced students in an SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to produce a query for a Placement Application Tracking System -  showing the number of students placed and unplaced by programme. Currently the query returns each programme's number of placed students in one row, unplaced in another:

```
    PROGRAMME_NAME                                | LABEL    | VALUE
    BSc (Hons) Computer Science                   | Placed   | 2 
    BSc (Hons) Computing and Games Development    | Unplaced | 1 
    BSc (Hons) Web Applications Development       | Unplaced | 1 
    BSc (Hons) Marine Biology and Coastal Ecology | Placed   | 1
    BSc (Hons) Computer Science                   | Unplaced | 2
```

However, I would like to output the query like so:

```
    PROGRAMME_NAME                                | PLACED   | UNPLACED
    BSc (Hons) Computer Science                   | 2        | 2 
    BSc (Hons) Computing and Games Development    | 1        | 0 
    BSc (Hons) Web Applications Development       | 0        | 1 
    BSc (Hons) Marine Biology and Coastal Ecology | 1        | 0
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT programme_name,
  CASE
    WHEN cv_approval_date     IS NOT NULL
    AND application_status_id != 7
    OR application_status_id  IS NULL
    THEN 'Unplaced'
    ELSE 'Placed'
  END      AS label,
  COUNT(*) AS value
FROM programme
LEFT JOIN student USING (programme_id)
LEFT JOIN application USING (student_id)
GROUP BY programme_name,
  CASE
    WHEN cv_approval_date     IS NOT NULL
    AND application_status_id != 7
    OR application_status_id  IS NULL
    THEN 'Unplaced'
    ELSE 'Placed'
  END;
```

How might I go about doing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT programme_name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN (cv_approval_date IS NOT NULL AND application_status_id <> 7) OR
                     application_status_id  IS NULL
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Unplaced,
       SUM(CASE WHEN (cv_approval_date IS NOT NULL AND application_status_id <> 7) OR
                     application_status_id  IS NULL
                THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as Placed
FROM programme LEFT JOIN
     student USING (programme_id) LEFT JOIN
     application USING (student_id)
GROUP BY programme_name;
```

Some notes:

- I replaced `!=` with `<>`.  The latter is the ANSI standard for the operator.
- I added parentheses for the conditions.  These are not strictly needed, but they clarify the logic.
- The two `case` statements are exactly the same, except the values for `then` and `else`.  This helps prevent errors in logic and ensures that all students are counted.
- `LEFT JOIN`s shouldn't be necessary, unless you have some programs with no students/applications.